# Connection Refused in reading JSON from PHP in localhost, Android Studio

Tags: php, android, json, connection

I'm trying to connect to one php on my localhost server that works ok, but I can't read the content there.

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.klaussius.probandoconexionservidor;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import serverDataRead.ReadUsers;

public class Principal extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView tvText;
    Button btGetInfo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);
        // TextView for our text
        tvText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvText);
        // Button to get text
        btGetInfo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btGetInfo);
        btGetInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new leerDatos().execute();
            }
        });
    }

private class leerDatos extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        ReadUsers reader = new ReadUsers();
        return reader.readUsers();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        tvText.setText(s);
        }
    }
}
```

And my method readUsers is in the class readUsers:

```
package serverDataRead;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class ReadUsers {
    public String texto;

    public String readUsers(){
        try {
            String link = "http://127.0.0.1/api/usersQuery.php";
            URL url = new URL(link);
            HttpURLConnection con = HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            texto = bufferedReader.readLine();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            texto = "Fail!";
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            return texto;
        }
    }
}
```

The layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btGetInfo"
        android:text="@string/getText" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tvText" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The error I get:
W/System.err: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using emulator rather than genymotion then use `10.0.2.2`  instead of  `localhost`  so the url will be  "`http://10.0.2.2/api/hostsQuery.php`" and if you use genymotion  then replace `localhost` with  `10.0.3.2`,so the url will be  `"http://10.0.3.2/api/hostsQuery.php"`

Let me know if this works for you

Comment: I have tryied with your fix, but I am getting the same error, I know the issue must to be there, so I also tried with:
http://my_ip/api/UsersQuery.php
But I cant access.

Thanks again.

Comment: @IvánVillaSánchez are you testing on a real device or emulator?

Comment: Im testing on one emulator

Comment: well try replacing localhost with the real ip of your computer something like 192.168.101.....

Comment: I tried it, but I get the same error. I dont know what could be happening here.

Comment: Ok, i was doing the things on a bad way.
10.0.2.2 finally worked for me, thanks very mucho for your help.

Comment: pleasure to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```